# One javascript function disables other functions

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I have 3 functions:

```
window.onload = function() {       
    canvas();   
    changeColor();
    blockSize();    
}
```

The problem is with third "blockSize()". It not running when I place it at the bottom of window.onlod function; + when I place it at the top, it disables all functions below it. Here is the code (calculates width and height in percentages of all blocks with className "size"):

```
function blockSize() {
    var block = document.getElementsByClassName("size");    
    for (var i in block) {       
        var width = Math.round(block[i].clientWidth/document.documentElement.clientWidth*100);
        var height = Math.round(block[i].clientHeight/document.documentElement.clientHeight*100);
        var span = document.createElement("span");
        span.innerHTML = width+"x"+height+"%";
        block[i].appendChild(span);
    }    
}
```

Noticed, that problem appers when I appendChild (last line). When I remove it, other functions works properly. Also tried to put < span> manually inside a div and use this javascript line instead (same results):

```
block[i].firstChild.innerHTML = width+"x"+height+"%";
```

!!! When I use only innerHTML, everything works fine. And I understand, that I can use something like this, and it will work:

```
block[i].innerHTML = "<span>"+width+"x"+height+"</span>";
```

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: Can you post the full code (the other functions)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem which could have been solved if the OP had simply looked at the console.

Comment: Here is the console code, it didn't tell me, that problem is in loop: 
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined`

Comment: Basic debugging.  Based on the error message, a quick insertion of a `console.log(block[i])` or a breakpoint in the debugger to look at things would have show you that you were iterating things you didn't want to iterate and then, at least, you could have included much better info in your question about the problem or perhaps seen yourself what was going on.  It's very important to learn basic debugging steps so you can examine what is going on yourself in the affected area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem most likely comes from improperly using `for-in` on an HTMLCollection. This will include other items besides DOM elements.

when it encounters the `block[i].appendChild(span)`, it'll throw an error if `block[i]` isn't an element and therefore doesn't have an `.appendChild()` method.

Use a `for` loop instead.

```
function blockSize() {
    var block = document.getElementsByClassName("size");    
    for (var i = 0; i < block.length; i++) {       
        var width = Math.round(block[i].clientWidth/document.documentElement.clientWidth*100);
        var height = Math.round(block[i].clientHeight/document.documentElement.clientHeight*100);
        var span = document.createElement("span");
        span.innerHTML = width+"x"+height+"%";
        block[i].appendChild(span);
    }    
}
```

Comment: Thanks, problem is fixed. Didn't expect that problem can be in `for-in`. For all next times will use only `for` loop.

Comment: @Mark1ra: yeah, in JS when dealing with Arrays or Array-like objects, it's best to use `for`.

Comment: A classic example of why one should never iterate an array with for/in.